# NVD3: multiChart wrong format for series

Tags: d3.js, charts, formatting, nvd3.js

I'm doing a chart using NVD3 multiChart model, I have 4 series, 3 bars associated with the left yAxis and 1 line associated with the right yAxis.

The 3 bars simply have a float value, where the line has a perchentage.
Everything works fine, but there is something off in the tooltip, the date it's not correctly formated (not formatted at all, acutally).

Do you have any idea how I can have the same date formatting the I have on the bottom ?

```
1458428400 -> 20-03-16
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn out it's a bug, in case anyone else need the patch you can use I've done a pull request:

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1406

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

1. Define a function that converts epoch to a nice date. Something like this:

   ```
   function epochToNiceDate(epoch) {
       var date = new Date(0);
       date.setUTCSeconds(epoch);
       var day = date.getDate();
       var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
       var year = date.getFullYear();
       return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
   }
   ```
2. Pass a content generator function for your tooltip to your chart (assuming you have **useInteractiveGuideline** enabled). You could browse the source code of NVD3 and copy/paste the default content generator and then modify it as you wish. Let's use the following one as an example:

   ```
   chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
       var tooltipTitle = epochToNiceDate(d.value);
       var tooltip = "";

       tooltip += "<table>";
       tooltip += "<thead>";
       tooltip += "<tr><td colspan='3'><strong class='x-value'>" + tooltipTitle + "</strong></td></tr>";
       tooltip += "</thead>";
       tooltip += "<tbody>"

       for(var i in d.series) {
           var currentSeries = d.series[i];
           var color = currentSeries.color;
           var key = currentSeries.key;
           var value = currentSeries.value;

           tooltip += "<tr>";
           tooltip += "   <td class='legend-color-guide'>";
           tooltip += "      <div style='background-color: " + color + ";'></div>";
           tooltip += "   </td>";
           tooltip += "   <td class='key'>" + key + "</td>";
           tooltip += "   <td class='value'>" + value + "</td>";
           tooltip += "</tr>";
       }

       tooltip += "</tbody>";
       tooltip += "</table>";

       return tooltip;
   });
   ```

You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/Luc93/qf4u5439/

Good luck!